# How to split event values in Google Data Studio with Calculated Fields

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, looker-studio

I'm trying to multiply the event value of a certain Event Action (A) by ($x.xx) and the event value of a different type of Event Action (B) by a different amount ($x.xx).

- Ex: Event Action A * 1.37
- Ex: Event Action B * 2.22

I have Google Tag Manager firing events per click, where the Action is the type of click and Label is the URL. In Google Data Studio, I understand I can use a Calculated Field to multiply [Event Value] by [x amount]. But I'm not sure how to separate this based on the event action.

Is it also possible to do this in one field? Such as:

If (Event Action contains "A" then multiply [event value] by [x], else if Event Action contains "B" then multiply [event value] by [y])

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do it in one step in one field but if you do one field (multiplier) as

```
CASE 
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH("Event Action","A") THEN [yourmultipliervalueX] 
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH("Event Action","B") THEN [yourmultipliervalueY] 
ELSE 0
END
```

And then a second field as

```
multiplier*[event value]
```

EDIT: To take into account [event value] being an aggregate

```
AVG(CASE 
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH("Event Action","A") THEN [yourmultipliervalueX] 
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH("Event Action","B") THEN [yourmultipliervalueY] 
ELSE 0
END)
```